# OpenShift import-image fails when behind corporate proxy

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, docker-registry

When i run

```
oc import-image centos:7 --confirm true
```

I am getting

```
The import completed with errors.

Name:                   centos
Namespace:              pd-kube-ci
Created:                Less than a second ago
Labels:                 <none>
Annotations:            openshift.io/image.dockerRepositoryCheck=2018-12-27T21:00:26Z
Docker Pull Spec:       docker-registry.default.svc:5000/pd-kube-ci/centos
Image Lookup:           local=false
Unique Images:          0
Tags:                   1

7
  tagged from centos:7

  ! error: Import failed (InternalError): Internal error occurred: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: EOF
      Less than a second ago

error: tag 7 failed: Internal error occurred: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: EOF
```

For the life of me, i cannot find the source of `proxyconnect tcp: EOF`.  Its not found anywhere in the OpenShift/Kubernetes source.  Google knows next to nothing about that.

I have also verified that i can `docker pull centos` from each node (including master and infra nodes).  Its only when openshift tries to pull that image.

Any ideas?

Comment: Based on the `docker-registry.default.svc` in the output, I'd guess you have an internal caching registry -- Is **it** correctly configured with http proxy settings? I'm having to hand-wave here because [the registry docs](https://docs.docker.com/v18.03/registry/configuration/) actually don't mention anything about http proxy usage, so you may be in uncharted territory

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel, are you saying that the registry container itself would be making the `https` request to `registry-1.docker.io/v2`?  I have yet to figure out which pieces of the k8s infra actually pull the images.  Further, it would be nice to see this same message show up in a log somewhere, but I have yet to see that either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a mis-configuration in our `openshift_https_proxy` ansible var.  Specifically we had:

```
openshift_https_proxy=https://proxy.mycompany.com:8443
```

And we should have had

```
openshift_https_proxy=http://proxy.mycompany.com:8443
```

To fix this, we had to edit `/etc/origin/master/master.env` on the masters and `/etc/sysconfig/docker` on all nodes, then restart per the [Working with HTTP Proxies](https://docs.okd.io/3.11/install_config/http_proxies.html) documentation.